# GridMove fullscreen

Tags: windows, grid

I`m using GridMove to organize my windows, but I have a problem with programming in a fullscreen option. Anyone else got some experience with this tool and can help me out?

THis is my current code, nr. 3 doesn`t work as (I) expected :

```
[1]

  TriggerTop   = [Monitor1Top]
  TriggerLeft  = [Monitor1Left]
  TriggerBottom= [Monitor1Top] + [Monitor1Height]
  TriggerRight = [Monitor1Left] + [Monitor1Width] / 2

  GridTop   = [Monitor1Top]
  GridLeft  = [Monitor1Left]
  GridBottom= [Monitor1Top] + [Monitor1Height]
  GridRight = [Monitor1Left] + [Monitor1Width] / 2

[2]

  TriggerTop   = [Monitor1Top]
  TriggerLeft  = [Monitor1Left] + [Monitor1Width] / 2
  TriggerBottom= [Monitor1Top] + [Monitor1Height]
  TriggerRight = [Monitor1Right]

  GridTop   = [Monitor1Top]
  GridLeft  = [Monitor1Left] + [Monitor1Width] / 2
  GridBottom= [Monitor1Top] + [Monitor1Height]
  GridRight = [Monitor1Right]

[3]

  TriggerTop   = [Monitor1Top]
  TriggerLeft  = [Monitor1Left] + [Monitor1Width]
  TriggerBottom= [Monitor1Top] + [Monitor1Height]
  TriggerRight = [Monitor1Right]

  GridTop   = [Monitor1Top]
  GridLeft  = [Monitor1Left] + [Monitor1Width]
  GridBottom= [Monitor1Top] + [Monitor1Height]
  GridRight = [Monitor1Right]
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

There is a bit of a confusion between the trigger area and the grid action.
Nr. 3 should have a triggering area that is not the whole monitor.

You should create a layout that put on the screen three **non-overlapping** rectangles using the Trigger* parameters, with the three desired actions in Grid*.

Comment: Hmm, but I have my three desired actions 1: Left 50%, 2: Right 50% and 3: Fullscreen. The last one doesn`t work though.

As for the triggers I see the third one overlap, but I don`t really use them anyway as I only use keyboard shortcuts.

Thanks!

Comment: That's the only problem I see with your layout. It may confuse GridMove, so perhaps it's better to fix it. For example, make 1 & 2 half-screen high, and let 3 have the entire bottom half of the screen.

Comment: I see, I tried this now, but no success :(

Comment: It might be a bug in GridMove, because there's nothing wrong that I can see. Try maybe to change the order, or delete those that work, and monkey around with what's left until you happen upon the problem. I don't have any better advice.

Answer (score 0):

Ack, it was actually a basic mistake, it should be :

```
[3]

  TriggerTop   = [Monitor1Top]
  TriggerLeft  = [Monitor1Left] + [Monitor1Width]
  TriggerBottom= [Monitor1Top] + [Monitor1Height]
  TriggerRight = [Monitor1Right]

  GridTop   = [Monitor1Top]
  GridLeft  = [Monitor1Left]
  GridBottom= [Monitor1Top] + [Monitor1Height]
  GridRight = [Monitor1Right]
```

The old one would actually make it 0 pixels wide.